# This question involves sampling distribution, standard errors, and probablilities of a random sample

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

Two candidates are running for the office of mayor for Statscity. The race is very close, and currently, Mr. E has 54% of the vote. A random sample of 1,000 voters is asked whether or not they will vote for Mr. E.

a.) Draw the expected curve representing sampling distribution for samples of 1,000 voters. Be sure to include the center and go out two standard errors above and below the mean. Round to three places.

b.) Find the probability that a random sample of voters will show 57% or more support Mr. E. Round three places.

c.) Would it be "unusual" to get a random sample where 63% plan to vote for Mr. E? Give a reason for your answer.

Comment: Do you have any thoughts?

Comment: For part a, I believe the center of the curve (the mean) would be 54% (or .54) and one standard error = .01576. So, if I go out 2 standard errors, from the right of my mean (.54) would be .56 & .58. To the left of my mean would be .50 & .52. This is just me guesstimating. I am not for sure.

Comment: also, I found my standard error by using the equation of: the square root of p times (1-p) over or divided by n. P stands for the population proportion & n is the total of the sample.